# How to recreate an existing node with all children with dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using arcgis javascript api to develop a webgis.
I want to destroy the "measurementID" node with some children when the user click on the "Deactive" button and then recreate the node with "Measurement" Button.
To destroy the node I use `dojo/dom-construct`  and destroy method in the module.
But I could not recreate the node. How can i recreate the node using dojo toolkit?

```js
registry.byId("deactivate").on("click", function() {

  domConstruct.destroy("mesurementID")

});
registry.byId("Measurement").on("click", function() {

  //       Recreate .... !
});
```

```html
<div id="mesurementID" style="position:absolute;  left:50px; top:100px;width: 150px;height: 15px; z-Index:999;border:solid;border-width: 1pt;border-color: black;">

  <div id="measurementDiv"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing.
Here are some possibilities:

```js
require(["dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/dom-class", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"], function(domConstruct, domClass, dom) {

  //destroy the node using plain javascript:
  var removedNode = dom.byId('test').removeChild(dom.byId('test1'));
  //and readd it to the page
  dom.byId('test').appendChild(removedNode);

  //or using domConstruct
  domConstruct.destroy(dom.byId('test1'));
  //and recreate it
  domConstruct.create('div', {
    id: 'test1',
    innerHTML: 'div with some content'
  }, dom.byId('test'));


  //or clone it
  var clonedNode = dom.byId('test1').cloneNode(true);
  domConstruct.destroy(dom.byId('test1'));
  //and readd it
  dom.byId('test').appendChild(clonedNode);


  //but better, make it hidden
  domClass.add(dom.byId('test1'), 'hidden');
  //and show it
  domClass.remove(dom.byId('test1'), 'hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">

<div id="test">
  <div id="test1">div with some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ben .I used hidden solution.